# Powershell Get-Module Questions

Tags: powershell

I am running PS 5.1.14393.4583.

If I run `get-module -listavailable` a list of modules gets returned including

- `PSReadline` in Directory: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
- `WebAdministration` in Directory:
  `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Both of the paths shown above are part of `$env:PSModulePath`

If I run `get-module -name PSReadline` the info for `PSReadline` is displayed however `get-module -name WebAdministration` returns nothing.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run `Import-Module WebAdministration` before running `get-module -name WebAdministration` ?

Comment: `PSReadLine` is automatically loaded on startup when `powershell.exe` is launched interactively, so the difference is that one has already been imported, the other has not.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for the response. I did but as running 'get-module -listavailable` showed the module was available I would expect 'get-module -name WebAdministration' to return something regardless, hence the question.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks for taking the time to respond. why would the fact that `PSReadLine` is automatically loaded on startup when `powershell.exe` is launched make a difference? Doesn't the fact that `get-module -listavailable` shows `WebAdministration` mean that `get-module -name WebAdministration` should find it also?